# Creating Venn diagram in C# win Form

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, onpaint

I need to create a Venn diagram in win form C#. I have been trying to do it using Graphics.DrawEllipse and FillElipse. But I am not sure how do I fill in the common part.

I want to achieve this,

[image]

Here is my code for this,

```
private void panelControlVennDiagram_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Brush brushLeft = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
  Brush brushRight = new SolidBrush(Color.LightPink);
  Brush brushCommon = new SolidBrush(Color.Purple);

  Pen pen = new Pen(brushLeft, 10);

  Rectangle leftVenn = new Rectangle(20, 50,100,100);
  Rectangle rightVenn = new Rectangle(90, 50, 100, 100);
  Rectangle commonVenn = new Rectangle(100, 120, 100, 100);

  Font stringFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 9);

  e.Graphics.DrawString("Left:" + leftValue, stringFont, brushLeft, 10,70);
  e.Graphics.DrawString("Right:" + rightValue, stringFont, brushRight, 90,70);
  e.Graphics.DrawString("Common:" + commonValue,stringFont, brushCommon, 100,70);

  // Fill ellipse on screen.
  e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brushLeft, leftVenn);
  e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brushRight, rightVenn);

  e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.White, leftVenn);
  e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.White, rightVenn);
```

}

I am drawing two ellipses and need to have a different color for the common part. I can not use any library. Please help.

Comment: Side note: Please dispose of all the brushes and pens or turn them into fields instead of local variable to re-use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `System.Drawing.Drawing2D;` namespace to use `GraphicPath`. Create a graphic path and get the intersection region.

Try this code: (I have commented `DrawString` for testing purpose)

```
private void panelControlVennDiagram_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle leftVenn = new Rectangle(20, 50, 100, 100);
    Rectangle rightVenn = new Rectangle(90, 50, 100, 100);          
    Region region1 = new Region();

    //Font stringFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 9);
    //e.Graphics.DrawString("Left:" , stringFont, brushLeft, 10, 70);
    //e.Graphics.DrawString("Right:" , stringFont, brushRight, 90, 70);
    //e.Graphics.DrawString("Common:", stringFont, brushCommon, 100, 70);

    // Fill ellipse on screen.
    using(Brush brushLeft = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
    {    
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brushLeft, leftVenn);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.White, leftVenn);
    }

    using(Brush brushRight = new SolidBrush(Color.LightPink))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brushRight, rightVenn);        
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.White, rightVenn);
    } 

    using (GraphicsPath circle_path = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        circle_path.AddEllipse(leftVenn);
        region1.Intersect(circle_path);
    }

    using (GraphicsPath circle_path = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        circle_path.AddEllipse(rightVenn);
        region1.Intersect(circle_path);
    }

    using(Brush brushCommon = new SolidBrush(Color.Purple))
    {  
        e.Graphics.FillRegion(brushCommon, region1);
    }

}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This works good... One more question related to this, I also would like to handle the mouse clicks on the left / right and common part of the venn diagram. How do I save the mouse location?

Answer (score 3):

you could use a semi-transparent color so that the color of the overlapping parts is the actual composite color of the two circles

```
Brush brushLeft = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Blue));
Brush brushRight = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red));
```

[image]

Comment: Can someone please advise on how to handle the mouse clicks on each of these regions... Left / Right / Common?